# C# Arrow Key is not captured

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a program, that is able to draw on the full desktop. I have different functions for drawing for example an ellipse. There is also a function for inserting some Text. For this I use a transparent `TextBox`(Tbx). When I call this function, it creates a `Label`, that gets the Text of the `Textbox`, everytime I change the text. This works quite well, but I also have a function that should minimize the `Window` with <kbd>↓</kbd>. After inserting text, the key is useless, but the other keys are still captured with the event handler. If I don't insert text into `Textbox` control, I can minimize. The main problem is, that the <kbd>↓</kbd> is not captured with the event handler and the minimization doesn't happen. I'm unsure if `KeyDownEvent` is the correct event to capture special keys such as arrows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, ... So the question is how to fix this code to capture <kbd>↓</kbd> and execute the code to minimize the `Window`.

Here are some parts of my code:

Creating a Label:

```
Tbx.Clear();
if (!hasStartPoint)
{
    START = current;
    hasStartPoint = true;
}
this.canvas1.Children.Remove(Lab2);
Lab1 = new Label() { IsEnabled = true, Background = Brushes.Transparent, Foreground = this.brush, FontFamily = textFont, Content = "" };
if (this.thickness > 5000) { FontSize = 5000; }
else { FontSize = this.thickness; }
Canvas.SetLeft(Lab1, START.X);
Canvas.SetTop(Lab1, START.Y);
Tbx.Focus();
isWriting = true;
this.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
canvas1.Children.Add(Lab1);
Lab2 = Lab1;
```

Writing text:

```
void Tbx_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isWriting)
    {
        Lab1.Content = Tbx.Text;
    }
}
```

Finished writing:

```
else if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.End)
{
    if (!isWriting)
    { this.Close(); }
    else
    {
        Lab1 = new Label() { IsEnabled = true, Background = Brushes.Transparent, Foreground = this.brush, FontSize = this.thickness, FontFamily = textFont, Content = "" };
        Canvas.SetLeft(Lab1, 1);
        Canvas.SetTop(Lab1, 1);
        canvas1.Children.Add(Lab1);
        isWriting = false;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
    }
 }
```

Minimizing the Window in a `KeyDownEvent`:

```
else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `PreviewKeyDownEvent`. Which allows for special keys such as arrows, Ctrl, ... This should help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for catching special keys is to use [`PreviewKeyDownEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx). This is because those keys are not considered to be input for some controls.

> Some key presses, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys, are
>   typically ignored by some controls because they are not considered
>   input key presses. For example, by default, a Button control ignores
>   the arrow keys. Pressing the arrow keys typically causes the focus to
>   move to the previous or next control. The arrow keys are considered
>   navigation keys and pressing these keys typically do not raise the
>   KeyDown event for a Button. However, pressing the arrow keys for a
>   Button does raise the PreviewKeyDown event. By handling the
>   PreviewKeyDown event for a Button and setting the IsInputKey property
>   to true, you can raise the KeyDown event when the arrow keys are
>   pressed. However, if you handle the arrow keys, the focus will no
>   longer move to the previous or next control.